# Why am I getting a different number of results when I change the formatting of the WHERE statement?

Tags: mysql, scripting

I am writing a SQL script (in MySQL Workbench, if that's relevant) that involves looking for variations of the same string in my data. This way, I can get an accurate pull even if something is misspelled. The script goes something like this:

```
SELECT A.Name, A.ID
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B on B.ID = A.ID
WHERE B.type = 1
AND (
B.notes LIKE '%apple%'
OR B.notes LIKE '%aple%'
OR B.notes LIKE '%appl%'
)
```

Because a single entry in table A can be linked to several different notes, which are kept in table B, if a single person has a note that contains "apple" and another that says "appl" they should show up twice, which is fine. After running this script, I got 9627 rows returned.

I tried the same script but changed the WHERE to this:

```
WHERE B.type = 1
AND (B.notes LIKE '%apple%'
OR '%aple%'
OR '%appl%')
```

and now I have 9929 rows.

Do these two different WHERE clauses function differently because I left out the B.notes in the second? I am working with large data sets (A has over 20,000 entries, B has over 1.6 million) so it's not particularly practical to go through and check all of the data's integrity by hand. I'm fairly new to SQL so I appreciate any information or suggestions as to why this happens and how to get an accurate result.

Comment: `OR 'aple'` is a condition for itself and returns false. Just like `OR 'appl'` So your  `where` simplifies to `WHERE B.type = 1 and B.notes LIKE 'apple'`

Comment: Also worth noting that `LIKE` without wild cards is the same as `=`.

Comment: But if my where is simplifying in the latter script, shouldn't that typically result in fewer rows? Since I'm using `OR` my understanding was that I would be getting results from all three variations above.
And I've edited above to include the wildcards. (I have them in my script but they got lost in translation. Oops!)

Comment: Yes, you should have been getting fewer results. If the wildcards were lost in translation, it is probably prudent to supply us with the full changed one as well. (Another thing worth noting is there is no need for a LEFT join in the first query.)

Comment: The full changed one as in my original script, or just writing out both scripts in my question?

Comment: Ideally the two complete versions of the queries actually executed, but we're used to some sensitivity to full disclosure around here so precise equivalents would work just as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because in one case you have a `LIKE` keyword before both 'aple' and 'appl', but on the other case you don't.

You could either try adding those in, or one way you could write it in shorthand is `AND B.notes IN ('apple', 'aple', 'appl')`.

Comment: When I tried using the `IN` it returned 0 rows. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I thought `IN` dealt primarily with numeric values?

And in terms of not having the `LIKE` keyword, is there a reason that might result in more rows as opposed to giving an error? I would presume that it's causing some of the rows to repeat, but I'm unsure of which ones, or why.